# How to check if my server's IP has somehow been blocked by some ISP?

Tags: isp, blacklist

I have an app, published on Play Store and App Store, that works via API with our webservices.
Nothing fancy, really really basic stuff.
Now, some customers can't use the app because it can't reach the servers.
I know the app is not reaching the server because I get no log whatsoever, not even of failed tasks. So I guess the api call is blocked from the start.
I'm assuming it's an ISP issue because of some tests we did with some customers. To be precise, customers using Vodafone aren't able to even log in. Customers using other ISPs or connecting to the internet via wi-fi can connect just fine.
We had an issue a few months ago because our IP got marked as phishing, but we solved it in a few hours and even Google cleared our reputation.
Is there a way to check if my assumptions are true? I tried any website to see if the domain or IP is blacklisted, with no success. We are clean.
But it can't be a coincidence that ONLY Vodafone customers aren't able to log in.
What can I do?

Comment: I used to have vodafone UK mobile, and their transparent proxying/filtering was a royal PITA. It blocked various sites that would generally considered to be necessary for normal browsing, such as imgur.com, and the blocking service wasn't able to be removed unless you called them up. Also, to make things more annoying, if you made any other changes via the web console, it reverted it to blocking stuff again, so you had to call them up to ask them again.

Comment: You'll have to contact Vodafone. I'm more familiar with email blacklists than with blacklists for other protocols, but I'd assume that if they have something actively blocking you, they'll have a way to contact them to get it removed.